# How to remove outline circle in this image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, outline

Can you guys suggest possible ways on how to remove the circle outline in this image? Imfindcircles doesnt work for me. Can you suggest other methods?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuD7v.jpg

[image]

Comment: use graythresh to separate background from foreground. make a mask with this threshold such as the background have 1's. dilate the background using imdilate, and apply to your binary image.

Comment: Sir I dont get the part where you have to dilate the background and apply it to your image. Can you elaborate on it more? Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `BW` to be the binary image that has the outline circled and which is to be removed, you can use an approach based on `regionprops` -

```
perimtrs = regionprops(BW, 'Perimeter'); %// perimeters for each connected component 
px = regionprops(BW, 'PixelIdxList'); %// pixel list for each connected component 
[~,idx] = max(struct2array(perimtrs)); %// get the component with max perimeter 
                                       %// that represents the outline circle
BW(px(idx).PixelIdxList) = 0;   %// Set all pixels of the outline circle to zero, 
                                %// that is they are removed
```

If you would like to be on the safest side with the functionality, you can use `BoundingBox` properties from `regionprops` instead of `'Perimeter'` as shown here -

```
%// Get the bounding box properties for each connected component
perimtrs = regionprops(BW, 'BoundingBox'); 

%// Get bounding box area for each component and get the ID for the largest
%// box that corresponds to the outline circle
bound_box = reshape(struct2array(perimtrs),4,[]);
bound_box_area = bound_box(3,:).*bound_box(4,:);
[~,idx] = max(bound_box_area);

%// Set the pixels corresponding to the outline circle to zeros
px = regionprops(BW, 'PixelIdxList');
BW(px(idx).PixelIdxList) = 0;
```

---

Alternatively, you can avoid the second use of `regionprops` to get the pixel list with a call to `regionprops` and that might be efficient with performance, but I haven't not tested, so can't guarantee that. The new approach would look something like this -

```
perimtrs = regionprops(BW, 'Perimeter');
[~,idx] = max(struct2array(perimtrs))
[L,num] = bwlabel( BW ); %// Label connected components
BW(L==idx)=0; %// Select all pixels corresponding to label idx and set those to zero
```

Similarly, you can mix this `bwlabel` approach with `BoundingBox` of `regionprops`.

Comment: sir, whenever i do what you say, it doesnt work on other images where there are blood vessels connected to the circle.

Comment: @Jamesmeister Link us to such a case?

Answer (score 1):

OK so here goes one hypotheses that does not assume the interface to be a circle, neither to be a single region, or having the largest perimeter.

```
%Assume A as your original image (left image), and bin_A as your binary image (right image)
thres=graythresh(A)
mask_A=im2bw(A,thres);
mask_A=imerode(mask_A,ones(3));
bin_A=bin_A.*mask_A;
```

Comment: i converted the original image into grayscale first before doing the thres part. the mask_A shows only pure white background. So after multiplying it to bin_A, the output was just the same with the right image.

Comment: please see the correction. the graythresh function gives a normalized intensity and not the correct one. that was probably why it was not working.